# How to add users, set passwords, and populate GECOS field from csv file?

Tags: bash, automation

I've set up / modified a script that takes input from a text file, creates new user accounts, sets an initial password, and expires the password forcing the users to change the password on first login.

The input file contents would look something like this just a plain text file with a list of usernames...

```
sdallas
smurky
mbloom
lgranola
pdubovich
sdabster
mbinkley
cjohn
bharlow
rasmith
```

The script I have is this...

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script to create users, set initial password, and force password reset upon first login.
# Takes input file with user names
# on the command line as the first argument
# Reset the <PASSWORD> value below with whatever initial password you wish to set for your users.

#User List File
USERLIST=$1

if [ "$USERLIST" = "" ]
then
    echo "Please specify an input file!"
    exit 10
elif test -e $USERLIST
then
    for user in `cat $USERLIST`
    do
            echo "Creating the "$user" user and setting initial password..."
        useradd -m $user && echo $user:<PASSWORD> | chpasswd && passwd -e $user         
    done
        echo "User must change password upon first login."
    exit 20
else
    echo "Invalid input file specified!"
    exit 30
fi
```

I am looking to extend this and am not sure how to approach it, but being able to append field 5 of the /etc/passwd file (The GECOS field).

I was thinking a csv file for the source file, soemthing like this...

```
sdallas,Steve,Dallas
smurky,Stef,Murky
mbloom,Milo,Bloom
lgranola,Lola,Granola
pdubovich,Pitr,Dubovich
sdabster,Sid,Dabster
mbinkley,Michael,Binkley
cjohn,Cutter,John
bharlow,Bobbi,Harlow
rasmith,Ronald-Ann,Smith
```

OR something like this...

```
sdallas,"Steve Dallas"
smurky,"Stef Murky"
mbloom,"Milo Bloom"
lgranola,"Lola Granola"
pdubovich,"Pitr Dubovich"
sdabster,"Sid Dabster"
mbinkley,"Michael Binkley"
cjohn,"Cutter John"
bharlow,"Bobbi Harlow"
rasmith,"Ronald-Ann Smith"
```

The question is then, how do I parse the .csv file out to get the fields separated for the proper variables? So I.E. I want variables such as $userid, and $userinfo

At that point I would I think update the following...

```
        echo "Creating the "$user" user and setting initial password..."
    useradd -m $user && echo $user:<PASSWORD> | chpasswd && passwd -e $user
```

to....

```
        echo "Creating the "$userid" user, poulating the user info, and setting initial password..."
    useradd -m -c $userinfo $userid && echo $user:<PASSWORD> | chpasswd && passwd -e $user
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: If you use `:` as csv delimiter instead of `,` you shouldn't need to quote anything as that's the passwd/group/shadow delimiter

Comment: instead of `for user in ...; do ...; done`, you can do `while IFS=: read -r login gecos; do ...; done <$USERLIST`